# Select Statement using php variable

Tags: php, sql, web

Got a problem trying to get this SQL query to work in my php. id is in the URL and then i want to use it as a variable $id with the select statement.. struggling to see what i am doing wrong

```
        require ("scripts/connect.php");

        if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
               $id = $_GET['id'];

        $get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM media WHERE id = '" . $id . "'"));
```

Comment: Don't put user input into your SQL queries. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: You've got at least two syntax errors there: Missing `}` and extra `)`.

Comment: Isn't the php interpreter telling you what is wrong? It should you `syntax error, unexpected ')'`

Comment: Indent the `$get` variable for readability and then close the `if`after the variable (you forgot a closing `}`). I also suggest, as a minimal injection protection, typehint `$id` with `(int)` in your SQL query. **That is the least you can do!**. Use prepared statements instead.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, i was getting  "currently unable to handle this request." message which wasn't much use really.  melpomene was right the extra ) caused this. There is an additional } but just didnt include it here as i knew it was the $get line causing the problem, dont know how i didnt spot the extra } myself.

Answer (score 0):

typo in the code:

```
   $get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM media WHERE id = '" . $id . "'"));
```

should be

```
$get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM media WHERE id = '" . $id . "'");
```

amd I agree with comments regarding user input in the query - uae PDO and parametised bound variables